# How can I upgrade to Xpath by adding a maven dependency? I can't find any repositories

Tags: xpath

I need to add XPath 2.0 to our project.  Is there a way to do this with pom dependency?  I know about saxon 9; but understand that there are issues about packaging it with maven. Any help?

Comment: [BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Maven) can be embedded using Maven and supports XQuery 3.0 (which is a superset of XPath 3.0). Make sure to understand the differences in the products anyway (streaming approach in Saxon, database approach in BaseX).

Answer (score 0):

Recent releases of Saxon are present in Maven.

(We resisted it for many years because Maven allows you to download JAR files without ever seeing the license conditions, which we felt contravened the license conditions for some third-party components that we use; but eventually we decided that since no-one else seems to care about this problem, we should ignore it too.)